# Drop down menu in Ruby on rails form_for with bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a drop down in my ruby on rails application. I have been able to create the drop down however I am not able to use the styling of Bootstrap. It is just creating a default dropdown as of now.

```
<%= form_for(@beverage, :html => {:class => "form-signin"}) do |f| %>
<div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.collection_select :status, Beverage::STATUS, :to_s, :to_s, :status =>true ,:class => "dropdown-menu"%>
</div>
```

In my beverage model I defined `STATUS` as

```
STATUS = ['hot', 'cold']
```

Is there a way to set the selected value as the value in :status?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use brackets when adding a class, otherwise it won't work, something like this:

```
{ :class => "dropdown-menu" }
```

**collection_select** has this parameters:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

And the value returned from calling **method** on the instance object will be selected.. maybe your method is returning nil..